# Counting Trello cards by month

Tags: trello

I want to count my cards in trello by month but trello doesn't have a feature to do this. Is there an easy way I can count trello cards by month? Is there available third party plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

The third party plugin can only count the cards in a list, like the Chrome plugin card counter(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cardcounter-for-trello/miejdnaildjcmahbhmfngfdoficmkdhi) and the FF plugin(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/trello-card-counter/).

They cannot count the cards after you filter the cards.

Perhaps you need to do it(by member, by month) yourself, use Trello API, or you can ask this question in this card: https://trello.com/c/NZ4bDwGs/11-trello-cardcounter.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the card creation dates from card ids using following:

```
for r in range(0, len(card_ids_list)):

    creation_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int("".join(list(card_id_list[r])[0:8]), 16)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This can be used in sorting and counting cards month wise.